# Reconnect to Database and restore backup

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I am using a Apache Derby DB and I would like to reconnect to it. While the program is running I would like to disconnect from the database and reconnect with the parameter of restoring the database from a backup. Something like this:

```
Connection connection;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:derby:myDb" ); //connection to the Database with the data from 2017-04-05
connection.close();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:derby:myDb;restoreFrom=/backup/2017-04-04/myDb" )
```

After running this I still see the Data from 2017-04-05 and not from 2017-04-04. Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like the restore failed? Perhaps because the database was still booted? What happens if you try using `shutdown=true` after you've closed all your connections, but before you perform the `restoreFrom`? https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefattrib16471.html

Comment: That's it. Thank you!